# How to insert ö/ä/ü in Database using php utf8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, utf-8

It was asked a dozen times, I know, but the only thing I want is to insert a German letter like 'Ä' into a database using a php script which simply doesn't work using the existing solutions.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password");

mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8mb4");
mysqli_select_db($con, "database");
mysqli_query($con, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =utf8mb4;");
mysqli_query($con, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =utf8mb4;");
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';");

mysqli_query($con,
"SET character_set_results = 'utf8',
character_set_client = 'utf8',
character_set_connection = 'utf8',
character_set_database = 'utf8',
character_set_server = 'utf8';");

$title = 'Ö';
$result = mysqli_query($con, 
"INSERT INTO Test (Title)
VALUES ('" . utf8_encode($title) . "');");
#Doesn't work, this was inserted: Ã
?>
```

The charset of the column 'Title' is set to utf8mb4_general_ci and of the Table itself its utf8_general_ci.
MySQL Server version is  5.5.31
MySQL Charset is UTF-8 Unicode

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong or am I missing something here?

Comment: `mysqli_query($con, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =latin1;");
mysqli_query($con, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =latin1;");` Should be utf8mb4 and not latin1.

Comment: Make sure the source of your data is submitting UTF8. If you don't specify your web page is UTF8, it might submit in something like Windows-1252

Comment: check phpMyAdmin your table settings, probably you need to switch charset for the table

Comment: thanks for you fast answers, I checked for the table charset, it's set to utf8_general_ci. I don't know how to make sure that the source of my data submitting is UTF8, but I added the header charset set to utf-8. And I also changed latin1 to uft8mb4.
But the problem is it still doesn't work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: If you remove utf8_encode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745672/mihai) said, I had to remove the utf8_encode() function, which messed the charset up. After removing it, it works as smooth as it should.